# Maximum Concurrent Threads that WCF supports?

Tags: multithreading, wcf

What is the maximum concurrent threads that WCF supports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF uses managed I/O threads from the CLR ThreadPool, so the max will be machine specific. Are you asking about the configuration of WCF throttling (MaxConcurrentCalls, MaxConcurrentInstances, and MaxConcurrentSessions)? If so, [take a look at this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2008/04/21/wcf-request-throttling-and-server-scalability.aspx), it should help explain how it works.